# How to deal with memory issure in Ctree in party package?

Tags: r, memory, party

I am using ctree method of the Party R package to generate a decision tree.

My dataset has about 22 columns and 650000 rows of data. I allocated 10GB of memory to my r session using memory.limit command.

I have a 2.3 GHz i3 processor and 6GB of RAM. what am i doing wrong here.

the error i get is

```
Calloc could not allocate memory (6223507 of 8 bytes)
```

Comment: If you only have 6GB RAM, allocating 10GB won't help in any way. Also, memory allocation problems in `ctree()` are usually caused by `factor` variables with too many unque levels. You have two solutions, either buckets them and hence reduce the number of unique levels, or weight every unique path and use `weights` in `ctree()`

Comment: I have modified my dataset to include columns with atmost 5 factor levels.. I still have about 20 columns and 6million rows.. can my computer do this job?

Comment: Give it a try. What is your explained variable btw? Is it binary or continious? Because if it's binary, you can weight the tree per unique path and significantly reduce the size of it

Comment: its a character vector with 3 levels.. still running out of memory..

Comment: I don't think can receive a character vector as explained variable. Only numeric , integer or factor

Comment: when i used str(myclass) , it showed me as a factor with 3 levels..

Comment: So its a factor then. Ok, let me write you a code to wieght your data and significantly reduce the size of it. You should come here more often btw to check for answers

Comment: Ok, I don't have time now, I'll try tod o it later today

Comment: sure I will.. I cannot thank you enough for your help. Actually I am in college right now..

Comment: Did you see my answer? did it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally found some time to do this. It's not the too elegant, but should work.
At first, load the libraries and the function below (you'll need to install `data.table` package)

```
library(data.table)
library(party)

WeightFunc <- function(data, DV){
# Creating some paste function in order to paste unique paths
paste2 <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = ",")
ignore <- DV

# Creating unique paths
test3 <- apply(data[setdiff(names(data),ignore)], 1, paste2)

# Binding the unique paths vector back to the original data
data <- cbind(data, test3)
#data

# Getting the values of each explaining variable per each unique path
dt <- data.table(data[setdiff(names(data), ignore)])
dt.out <- as.data.frame(dt[, head(.SD, 1), by = test3])

# Creating dummy variables per each value of our dependable variable for further calculations
DVLvs <- as.character(unique(data[, DV]))
data[, DVLvs[1]] <- ifelse(data[, DV] == DVLvs[1], 1, 0)
data[, DVLvs[2]] <- ifelse(data[, DV] == DVLvs[2], 1, 0)
data[, DVLvs[3]] <- ifelse(data[, DV] == DVLvs[3], 1, 0)

# Summing dummy variables per unique path
dt <- data.table(data[c("test3", DVLvs)])
dt.out2 <- as.data.frame(dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = test3])

# Binding unique pathes with sums
dt.out2$test3 <- dt.out$test3 <- NULL
test <- cbind(dt.out, dt.out2)

# Duplicating the data in order to create a weights for every level of expalined variable
test2 <- test[rep(1:nrow(test),each = 3), ]  
test2 <- cbind(test2, AdjDV = DVLvs)
test2$Weights <- ifelse(is.element(seq(1:nrow(test2)), grep("[.]1", rownames(test2))), test2[, DVLvs[2]], 
                        ifelse(is.element(seq(1:nrow(test2)), grep("[.]2",rownames(test2))), test2[, DVLvs[3]], test2[, DVLvs[1]]))

# Deleting unseassery column
test2[, DVLvs[1]] <- test2[, DVLvs[2]] <- test2[, DVLvs[3]] <- NULL

return(test2)
}
```

Now run this function on your data set where `data` is your data and `DV` is your explained variable name (in quotes) and save it in a new dataset, for example:

```
Newdata <- WeightFunc(data = Mydata, DV = "Success")
```

Now, this process could take a while if you have many unique pathes, but it shouldn't overload your memory. If you don't have too many unique paths, this function should reduce your data set by tens or even hundred times. Also, this function is only good for 3 level factor explained variable (like you have).

After that, you can run the `ctree` as you were doing previously, but with the new data and the new explained variable (**which will be called** `AdjDV`) and wiegths parameter **which called** `Weights`. You'll also have to exclude `Weights` out of the dataset while running the `ctree`. 
Like that:

```
ct <- ctree(AdjDV ~., data = Newdata[setdiff(names(Newdata), "Weights")], weights = Newdata$Weights)
```